# What is the standard terminology for proficiency?

Tags: dnd-5e, proficiency, terminology

I’ve seen a few things that say “you are proficient with X”, other things that say “you have proficiency with X”, and still others that say “you gain proficiency in X”. Is there a standard for these? For example, is one used for skills, one used for weapons, etc.?

Comment: Is this simple curiosity or are you looking to use consistent language e. g. for homebrew content?

Comment: @Akixkisu for homebrew content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### There are some trends based on the slight differences in meaning.

The books use the different wordings based on when you would normally use them in the English language.

The official [D&D Style Guide](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/267467) (p. 8 in v. 1.08a) addresses the difference between 'in' and 'with':

- You are proficient or have/gain proficiency **in** a skill, language, or other activity that is learnable and repeatable.
- You are proficient or have/gain proficiency **with** a tool, weapon, type of armor, or other object.

Looking through all the books there are some clear other trends too:

- Racial features generally use 'have proficiency'. The features are picked at the start of character creation and don't generally change going forward, so you don't really 'gain' them as much as just have them from 'birth'.
- Class features generally use 'gain proficiency'. Following the same reasoning as above but the other way around, class features are gained as your character grows.
- Spells generally use 'have proficiency'. This is likely done because these effects are generally temporary, you have proficiency for a duration. It wouldn't be wrong to use 'gain' but there is a slight implication that once gained it has to be then ungained. The intent would obviously still be clear but using 'have' is ever so slightly clearer.
- Magic items use both wordings but not at random. Generally they use 'gain', except for when the effect is either temporary or a restriction is specified in the description (like 'while wearing/wielding' or 'while attuned').
- That leaves 'is/are proficient'. This is generally not used for features granting a proficiency, instead it is used in restrictions: 'if you are proficient with'.

In conclusion, there are clearly some preferred wordings used depending on the context. There are obviously exceptions, so it's best to always think for yourself which wording works best in your situation.

Comment: I don't know that this is really helpful, but across all the published (sub)class features I found only three instances of "proficient" where it wasn't part of a restriction or conditional: Knowledge Cleric's Blessing of Knowledge: "You also become proficient in your choice of two of the following skills: Arcana, History, Nature, or Religion." Sun Soul Monk's Radiant Sun Bolt: "You are proficient with it" Pact of the Blade: "You are proficient with it while you wield it."

Comment: Apparently, you are proficient *in* a skill or saving throw, and *with* a weapon or tool.

Comment: It's also worth referencing the "Proficiency" section of the official [D&D Style Guide](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/267467) (p. 8 in v. 1.08a): "Here are the rules of thumb for using the right preposition with the words “proficient” and “proficiency”: • You are proficient, or have proficiency, **in** a skill, language, or other activity that is learnable and repeatable. • You are proficient, or have proficiency, **with** a tool, weapon, type of armor, or other object. For example, you might be proficient in Elvish and Arcana, and you might be proficient with longswords and heavy armor."